# How can I make html text surround itself with a round border, similar to an inactive button?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to surround my text with a rounded border, almost like a button. I don't want the inside of the border to be filled with color, I just want the border.

I keep trying methods but my borders only fill the `<div>` borders and not surround the text in a border.

```html
<p class="lead" style="font-size:200%;color: #F58EA6;">
    <br>
    <b>create your bucket</b>
</p>
```

EDIT:
I'm at here now:
[image]

My code:

```html
          <div style="margin: 0;padding: 0;box-sizing: border-box;">
          <p class="lead" style="font-size:200%;color: #F58EA6;border: 1px solid;width: 370px;height: 100px;padding: 5px 5px;
          border-radius: 10px;margin: 20px auto;display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;flex-direction: column;
          line-height: 35px;box-sizing: border-box;"><br>
                   <b>create your bucket</b></p>
                   </div>
```

Trying to solve for the space above, I tried using a vertical align but that didn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not styling the `div` `border`, it's the `p` tag actually, since the `p` tag (a paragraph) styled *100%* `width` by default. Style the `p` and give it a specific `width`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.myDiv {
}

.lead {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 400px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
  <p class="lead" style="font-size:200%;color: #F58EA6;">
    Example
    <br>
    <b>create your bucket</b>
  </p>
</div>
```

**EDITED:**
 Centered content at any `height`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.myDiv {
}

.lead {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    color: #F58EA6;
    font-size: 25px;

    /*DELETED*/
    /*height: auto*/
    /*text-align: center;*/

    /*ADDED*/
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
  <p class="lead">
    Example
    <br>
    <b>create your bucket</b>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I managed to get it to work much better using your code, although I have alot of space at the top. I added a picture of the html in my original post. Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: You're welcome, and the second solution added to the answer check it please.

Comment: I just tried making your edits, it looks like it improved by a little but I'm still getting that annoying white space above. I updated my code above.

Comment: Ohhh! it's the `<br>` tag! lol a new empty line added before the text

Comment: LOL. That had me running in circles and I wouldn't have caught it if you did. I was going crazy trying to figure out what went wrong. Thank you so much for making my night and giving me a laugh.

Comment: Hahaha, it's a pleasure my friend, anything anytime.

Answer (score 0):

use css property
`border-radius:8px`

Answer (score 0):

Use `border: 1px solid black;` to display the black border with 1px size around it. Then use `border-radius: 10px;` for example to round the corners. The sizes I wrote are just for example, use sizes that suit your need.

Comment: How can I shrink the div to surround the text? I updated my OG post if you want to take a look.